# pcl package missing in Hydro

Tags: pcl, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using Ros-Hydro in Ubuntu.
While I tried to 'rosmake robotino_node', I got the following dependency error:

...

Failed to invoke /opt/ros/hydro/bin/rospack deps-manifests robotino_node
[rospack] Error: package/stack 'robotino_node' depends on non-existent package 'pcl' and rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling 'rosdep update'

CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):

```
Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'robotino_node'.
Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the
broken dependency!
```

...

When I checked the installed packages from 'rospack list', there were three packages related to pcl:
pcl_conversions, pcl_msgs, pcl_ros
but no 'pcl' package.

How do I install the package to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/185215/pcl-package-missing-in-hydro/) by [kenomuseki](https://answers.ros.org/users/19583/kenomuseki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With catkin (groovy/hydro) there are no separate packages for OpenCV and PCL anymore. However, apparently the package you mentioned still uses rosmake, which historically requires these packages, if applied.... I am not really sure what is the best way in this case, but I'd try to remove pcl and opencv2 from the dependencies in manifest.xml and add to CMakeLists.txt something like

```
find_package( PCL 1.2 REQUIRED segmentation filters visualization )
```

You might need to add further:

```
include_directories(  ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
```

and link your targets accordingly:

```
target_link_libraries ( your_exec ${PCL_LIBRARIES}  )
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kenomuseki](https://answers.ros.org/users/19583/kenomuseki/) on 2014-07-07**:
I followed your instruction to get new error message as follows:

...

{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/jiwung/catkin_ws/src/robotino-ros-pkg/robotino/robotino_node/build'
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/robotino_node.dir/src/KinectROS.cpp.o
/home/jiwung/catkin_ws/src/robotino-ros-pkg/robotino/robotino_node/src/KinectROS.cpp: In member function ‘void KinectROS::depthEvent(const short unsigned int*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)’:
/home/jiwung/catkin_ws/src/robotino-ros-pkg/robotino/robotino_node/src/KinectROS.cpp:89:22: error: cannot convert ‘ros::Time’ to ‘uint64_t {aka long unsigned int}’ in assignment
In file included from /usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/point_cloud.h:50:0,
from /opt/ros/hydro/include/pcl_ros/point_cloud.h:5,
from /home/jiwung/catkin_ws/src/robotino-ros-pkg/robotino/robotino_node/include/

...

**Comment by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on 2014-07-14**:
Hi kenomuseki,

this is a conversion error. Please see http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Migration#PCL :)